# How to change comment string used by comment-region?

Tags: latex, comment

Emacs generally comments regions well, but sometimes I wish I could change the string it prepends to lines.  For example, in LaTeX, I would like to have a commented region only use a single `%` per line instead of two, i.e.,

```
% First line of commented region
% Second line of commented region
% Third line of commented region
```

Instead of

```
%% First line of commented region
%% Second line of commented region
%% Third line of commented region
```

I assume one could just set some variable for `latex-mode` in `.emacs.el`, but I could not find the variable name.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 12):

`comment-add`:

> comment-add is a variable defined in `newcomment.el`. Its value is 1
>   Local in buffer .emacs; global value is 0
>
> Documentation: How many more comment chars should be inserted by
>   `comment-region`. This determines the default value of the numeric
>   argument of `comment-region`. The `plain` comment style doubles this
>   value.
>
> This should generally stay 0, except for a few modes like Lisp where
>   it is 1 so that regions are commented with two or three semi-colons.

Use:

```
(add-hook 'latex-mode-hook (lambda () (setq-local comment-add 0)))
```

to get the behavior you want.

I found this variable with `helm-apropos`. You can also search with the built-in command `M-x apropos-variable`.

Comment: A bit more context: the string inserted to start a comment is defined by the variable `comment-start`, which for latex mode is `%`. As @nanny points out the variable `command-add` is used in modes like lisp and latex where the default  behavior is to insert the `comment-start` string multiple times.